# Computing weighted average of integer values

Tags: c++

i have this question from my CS class and i dont know if i understand what iam supposed to do even tho it sounds simple enough.

the question goes as follows:

**The grade in any course is calculated as follows:
A. The weight of the first exercise is 10% of the grade.
B. The weight of the second exercise is 20% of the grade.
C. And the weight of the third exam is 70% of the grade.
Write a program that reads from the user the grade in each of the three components, and displays the final grade in the course.**

this is my go at it:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

    int num1, num2, num3;
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

    int val1 = (num1 * 10) / 100;
    int val2 = (num2 * 20) / 100;
    int val3 = (num3 * 70) / 100;

    cout << "your total is: " << val1 + val2 + val3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

is that it or am i missing something.
any advice would help, thanks.

Comment: Whether or not you're missing something can be determined by your answer to the following question: in C++ what is `50` divided by `100`? It's possible that this homework assignment is meant to determine whether you understand how integer division works in C++, but it's hard to tell. It may very well be a simple test of knowing how to do basic operations in C++, too.

Comment: You need to declare the variables as float/double, since they might be decimal numbers.

Comment: Your *calculations* seem okay but you may want to improve the user experience a little. As in prompt for each grade, for example.

Comment: Do the division at the end:- ` int val1 = (num1 * 10);
    int val2 = (num2 * 20);
    int val3 = (num3 * 70); cout << "your total is: " << (val1 + val2 + val3)/100 << endl;` if you want to round to nearest % up or down add 50 thus:-cout << "your total is: " << (val1 + val2 + val3+50)/100 << '%' << endl;`

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing integer truncation, which is a result of the non-integer residual being discarded after division. This introduces error at every step of the process, so by the time you add the weighted sub-parts together, the errors are compounded.

A simple fix you can apply is to avoid dividing until the end. That is, you compute the weighted sum first, and then divide by the total weight:

```
int grade = (num1 * 10 + num2 * 20 + num3 * 70) / 100;
```

Technically you can divide all your weights by 10 here, but let's just keep them as percentages. It doesn't make a difference in this case (assuming your grades are not enormous numbers that could overflow when weighted).

If you need the result to be *rounded* before truncation, you can add another *half* of the denominator.

```
int grade = (num1 * 10 + num2 * 20 + num3 * 70 + 50) / 100;
```